# How to use Breakpoints in Axon Framework without having the event stream closed

Tags: debugging, breakpoints, axon

I'm using the AXON Framework a multi-service java spring application.

Everytime i debugg my application and set a breakpoint (e.g. in an Eventhandler method) I recieve the folowing error after a few seconds:

```
org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.AxonServerException: The Event Stream has been closed, so no further events can be retrieved
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.event.axon.EventBuffer.peekNullable(EventBuffer.java:178) ~[axon-server-connector-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.axonframework.axonserver.connector.event.axon.EventBuffer.hasNextAvailable(EventBuffer.java:144) ~[axon-server-connector-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processBatch(TrackingEventProcessor.java:385) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:292) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1003) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:1146) ~[axon-messaging-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: CANCEL
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535) ~[grpc-api-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:478) ~[grpc-stub-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:553) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:68) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:739) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:718) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.36.1.jar:1.36.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Is there any configuration trick, that allows me to use breakpoints without having the event stream closed?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of try and error I was able to solve this problem with the folowing entries in the AXON-Server's properties file (.../config/axonserver.properties)

```
axoniq.axonserver.keep-alive-time=0
axoniq.axonserver.keep-alive-timeout=604800000
axoniq.axonserver.min-keep-alive-time=604800000
```

Thes way the timeout only occures afer one week. This may cause problems in a production environment, but since I use a seperated axon server on my localhost machine for testing this is no problem for me.

This article helped figuring it out: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-server/administration/admin-configuration/configuration